# Updating d3 nodes with forEach() versus map()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 force layout graph, that when the page loads, displays 4 nodes with  the correct data bound perfectly. Then I give the user an option to click a button which essentially changes my entire visualisation in terms of the number of nodes (should now be 10), and ALL the data behind it (i.e. none of the info applying to the 4 initial nodes is relevant).

On pageload, I get my data like this...

```
var nodes = theData.map(function (d, i) {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * m);

                    return {
                        radius: circleRadiusScale(d.entity_count),
                        person: d.person,
                        cx: clusterScale(random), 
                        cy: height / 2
                    };
        });
```

Then on my "change all the data button" I have the same approach...

```
function updateNodeData(dataToUpdate) {
        nodes = null;   
        nodes = dataToUpdate.map(function (d, i) {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * m);
                    return {
                        radius: circleRadiusScale(dataToUpdate[i].entity_count),
                        person: dataToUpdate[i].person,
                        cx: clusterScale(random), 
                        cy: height / 2
                    };
        });                             
}
```

The problem with the above code, is that although it ensures an additional 6 nodes are added, the data for the 4 I started with is not updated.  I began by thinking that I had a problem with my update/exit selections, but then I tried this code in the "change all the data button"...

```
function updateNodeData(dataToUpdate) {
        nodes.forEach(function (d, i){  
                        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * m);

                        d.radius = circleRadiusScale(dataToUpdate[i].entity_count);
                        d.person = dataToUpdate[i].person;
                        d.cx = clusterScale(random); 
                        d.cy = height / 2;
        });                         
}
```

For this nodes.forEach approach, the data for the 4 nodes I started with is successfully updated (but of course, now I don't have the new 6 nodes on the page).

What's really strange to me, is that if I use combine both approaches in the same button (i.e. map the new data so that I have 10 elements, and then do the forEach() so they're updated), then I just get exactly the same result as I started with - 10 elements, where only 6 are correct.

Really hoping that sounds familiar to someone, and that I'm missing something basic about these map() and forEach() functions.  Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Apologies all but this WAS a problem with my update definition.  After I read Lars' comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427274/why-does-d3-not-update-the-text I realised I was incorrectly updating my data with SelectAll instead of Select.  Still not sure how that explains the different behaviour with forEach() and map(), but it's fixed the issue now and everything is updating perfectly.